# Can element in html body that is empty did not display and did not take up space

Tags: html, oracle, plsql

I have been using html inside pl/sql. The body of the html having the element c_address2. This element sometimes have value but sometimes it is null. When it has value i want to display it, when it is empty i do not want it to take up empty space. How should i write my html, or should i modify it in the pl/sql part?

```
  <body>
  <br><b><u>Ship To </u></b></br>
  <br>' || c_name || '</br>
  <br>' || c_address1 || '</br>
  <br>' || c_address2 || '</br>
  <br>' || c_city || '</br>
  <br>' || c_state || '<span style="margin-left:96px">' || c_postal_code || '</span></br>
  <br>' || c_country || '</br></body>
```

Comment: JavaScript it to remove html if empty

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing `<br>` tags (which are not containers by the way) by `<div>` tags.

The div tag will (if no css applied) not take any height if empty.

You will still se static content like "Ship to".

Note: It is usually not recommended to put display code in the database for various reasons.

Comment: I'm glad, could you mark the answer as "answered" then ? Thanks